# Can objects have a property by having other properties alone?

Tags: metaphysics

Can objects have properties just by having other properties?

For example: the leaf is green because it is alive (and other attributes).

Is it green only because it is alive (and other attributes) or does it take some other power to be green?

Comment: See Locke's famous [Primary–secondary quality distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary%E2%80%93secondary_quality_distinction): *Primary qualities are thought to be properties of objects that are independent of any observer, such as solidity, extension, motion, number and figure. These characteristics convey facts. They exist in the thing itself... Secondary qualities are thought to be properties that produce sensations in observers, such as color, taste, smell, and sound... These qualities would ordinarily be said to be only a power in rather than a quality of the object...*

Comment: The reason that leaves are green is the pre dominant wavelengths of light emitted in the visible spectrum by the sun lie in the green. The second most wavelengths emitted in the visible spectrum are red. When you combine light (light is color additive, not color subtractive like paints) you get yellow.

Answer (score 1):

An example is **emergence**, where the whole has the properties of the parts but their interaction produces novel properties in the whole, which however manifest because of the interplay of the parts' properties.

> In philosophy, systems theory, science, and art, emergence occurs when
> an entity is observed to have properties its parts do not have on
> their own, properties or behaviors which emerge only when the parts
> interact in a wider whole.

[Emergence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence)

So different properties of the parts give rise to different novel emergent properties. Thus one can say that the part's properties lead to the whole having certain new properties and not others.

Similar thoughts have been expressed by [Gestalt theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology):

> Gestalt psychologists emphasized that organisms perceive entire
> patterns or configurations, not merely individual components. The
> view is sometimes summarized using the adage, "the whole is more than
> the sum of its parts."

Answer (score 1):

If say we consider a property of something to be a predicate asserted of that thing, then, yes, this is of course possible. This is simply because more complex properties, that is predicates, can be made up of more simple ones. For example a tree has a trunk *and* branches.

This is straightforward. However, more sophisticated properties may not be amenable to such a simple description. Physicalists will disagree because they assume by conviction that all properties can be reduced to propositions of physics and hence predicates. But not everyone agrees with the physicalist positon. A famous one is the mind-body problem. The physicalist will simply say that the mind is merely a complex predicate made from physical propositions about the constitution of the body. Whereas others will argue that the mind cannot be reduced to the body or to matter in motion and is something other. A non-religious version of this argument will argue that the mind *supervenes* on the body and *emerges* somehow from it but is not reducible to it. Whereas a Christian or muslim will say the mind is an aspect of the soul and of course not reducible to the mere matter of the body.

The other point to understand is that properties - despite how we talk of them - do not stand alone but live in a larger environment. This is an ontological mistake and made very often by reductionists. It is why in philosophical Buddhism, properties by themselves are empty. They mean nothing. It is the whole that is real and which gives meaning and reality to its parts. The same is true in the classical theology of Christianity & Islam where one has to understand by the whole as that divinity named as Allah or God and the parts here that I am talking about are the parts in the cosmos - and not what someone who has argued with me on this site - as parts of God/Allah. Neither God/Allah in classical theology have parts, or rather, it is that they transcend them.